# Validate whether or not string is enum value

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a TypeScript `enum`

```
enum Items {
  One = 1,
  Two,
}
```

How can I know whether or not `string` `s` is a valid string representation of `Items`? For instance, `'One'` is valid but `'1'` isn't.

Comment: Are you just looking for `s in Items` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJAAVm)?  (I wouldn't call it a "valid string representation of `Items`".. it's a *key* of the enum object.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) get mapped to objects in JavaScript, so you can do the following:

```
enum Items {
  One = 1,
  Two,
}

function isEnumValue(s: string): s is keyof typeof Items {
    return s in Items;
}
```

There is a potential edge case here, because [numeric enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) also automatically get a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings). Passing a string representation of a numeric enum value into the above function, would also make the function return `true`:

```
console.log(isEnumValue('1')); // true
```

If needed, this can be addressed by additionally making sure that the key lookup returns a numeric value:

```
function isEnumValue(s: string): s is keyof typeof Items {
    return s in Items && typeof Items[s as any] === 'number';
}

console.log(isEnumValue('One')); // true
console.log(isEnumValue('1')); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

For static type checking, use:

```
enum Items {
    One = 1,
    Two,
}

const a1: keyof typeof Items = "One"  // OK
const a2: keyof typeof Items = 1  // not OK

const b1: keyof typeof Items = "Two"  // OK
const b2: keyof typeof Items = 2  // not OK

// Reduce typing whole "keyof typeof Items"
type Valid = keyof typeof Items

const c1: Valid = "One"  // OK
const c2: Valid = 1  // not OK
```

```
enum Items {
    One = 1,
    Two,
}

const a1: keyof typeof Items = "One"  // OK
const a2: keyof typeof Items = 1  // not OK

const b1: keyof typeof Items = "Two"  // OK
const b2: keyof typeof Items ...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgLsCBnKBvAUFLUDyJhQC8UAjADSbYAqA7gPYUC+66AxnSEnFAIYkBcUANbAAnnQBmUOKIAOwSbATIiUAER5garAHoduANJsOXXgCZBI8VJnzF8RCmIld+kHW44jxztwBGAsJiirYKUg4qxGq0dNpQeoY+pn4WQdbScmFKjqpmrlDunt4JAErAACZgrAS2AJYgAOZQNAAWdAA2BGpWIZn2ykhq6KFQAGo87bXlqj02feEDLOy+UKyB45PTUZpxCV5J3KypG1OqLvFuHolAA)

```
Type '1' is not assignable to type '"One" | "Two"'.
Type '2' is not assignable to type '"One" | "Two"'.
Type '1' is not assignable to type '"One" | "Two"'.
```